# Dispatch issue with generic subclass of custom table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

My application has a common base class for all table controllers, and I'm experiencing a strange bug when I define a generic subclass of that table controller base class. The method `numberOfSections(in:)` never gets called if and only if my subclass is generic.

Below is the smallest reproduction I could make:

```
class BaseTableViewController: UIViewController {
  let tableView: UITableView

  init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: style)

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  // MARK: - Overridden methods

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super. viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
  }
}

extension BaseTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
  }
}

extension BaseTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

Here's the very simple generic subclass:

```
class ViewController<X>: BaseTableViewController {
  let data: X

  init(data: X) {
    self.data = data
    super.init(style: .grouped)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // THIS IS NEVER CALLED!
    print("called numberOfSections")
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("called numberOfRows for section \(section)")
    return 2
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellFor: (\(indexPath.section), \(indexPath.row))")
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel!.text = "foo \(indexPath.row) \(String(describing: self.data))"

    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("didSelect: (\(indexPath.section), \(indexPath.row))")
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  }
}
```

If I create a simple app that does nothing but display ViewController:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController(data: 3))
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
  }
}
```

The table draws correctly but `numberOfSections(in:)` is never called! As a result, the table only shows one section (presumably because, according to the docs, `UITableView` uses 1 for this value if the method isn't implemented).

However, if I remove the generic declaration from the class:

```
class ViewController: CustomTableViewController {
  let data: Int

  init(data: Int) {
  ....
  }

  // ...
}
```

then `numberOfSections` DOES get called!

This behavior doesn't make any sense to me. I can work around it by defining `numberOfSections` in `CustomTableViewController` and then having `ViewController` explicitly override that function, but that doesn't seem like the correct solution: I would have to do it for any method in `UITableViewDataSource` that has this problem.

Comment: Probably unrelated but you should not override `loadView` unless you are directly setting `self.view`. And when you do that, don't call `super.loadView()`. The code you have in your `loadView` should be in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug / shortcoming within the generic subsystem of swift, in conjunction with optional (and therefore: `@objc`) protocol functions.

**Solution first**

You'll have to specify `@objc` for *all* the optional protocol implementations in your subclass. If there is a naming difference between the Objective C selector and the swift function name, you'll also have to specify the Objective C selector name in parantheses like `@objc (numberOfSectionsInTableView:)`

```
@objc (numberOfSectionsInTableView:)
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // this is now called!
    print("called numberOfSections")
    return 1
}
```

For non-generic subclasses, this already has been fixed in Swift 4, but obviously not for generic subclasses.

**Reproduce**

You can reproduce it quite easy in a playground:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol DoItProtocol {
    @objc optional func doIt()
}

class Base : NSObject, DoItProtocol {
    func baseMethod() {
        let theDoer = self as DoItProtocol
        theDoer.doIt!() // Will crash if used by GenericSubclass<X>
    }
}

class NormalSubclass : Base {
    var value:Int

    init(val:Int) {
        self.value = val
    }

    func doIt() {
        print("Doing \(value)")
    }
}

class GenericSubclass<X> : Base {
    var value:X

    init(val:X) {
        self.value = val
    }

    func doIt() {
        print("Doing \(value)")
    }
}
```

Now when we use it without generics, everything works find:

```
let normal = NormalSubclass(val:42)
normal.doIt()         // Doing 42
normal.baseMethod()   // Doing 42
```

When using a generic subclass, the `baseMethod` call crashes:

```
let generic = GenericSubclass(val:5)
generic.doIt()       // Doing 5
generic.baseMethod() // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
```

Interestingly, the `doIt` selector could not be found in the `GenericSubclass`, although we just called it before:

> 2018-01-14 22:23:16.234745+0100 GenericTableViewControllerSubclass[13234:3471799] -[*TtGC34GenericTableViewControllerSubclass15GenericSubclassSi* doIt]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800001a8d0
>   2018-01-14 22:23:16.243702+0100 GenericTableViewControllerSubclass[13234:3471799] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[*TtGC34GenericTableViewControllerSubclass15GenericSubclassSi* doIt]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800001a8d0'

(error message taken from a "real" project)

So somehow the selector (e.g. Objective C method name) cannot be found.
Workaround: Add `@objc` to the subclass, as before. In this case we don't even need to specify a distinct method name, since the swift func name equals the Objective C selector name:

```
class GenericSubclass<X> : Base {
    var value:X

    init(val:X) {
        self.value = val
    }

    @objc
    func doIt() {
        print("Doing \(value)")
    }
}

let generic = GenericSubclass(val:5)
generic.doIt()       // Doing 5
generic.baseMethod() // Doing 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. Using @objc for the optional methods and using the correct selector name for the specific case of `numberOfSections` does exactly what I need. Where is it documented that the Objective-C name of `numberOfSections` differs from the Swift name?

Comment: I noticed that the same problem occurs with `didSelectRow` - its Objective-C selector doesn't match its Swift name. Using the correct Objective-C selector in @objc fixes that problemt oo

Answer (score 2):

If you provide default implementations of the delegate methods (`numberOfSections(in:)`, etc.) in your base class and override them in your subclasses where appropriate, they will be called:

```
extension BaseTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
  ...

class ViewController<X>: BaseTableViewController {
  ...
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // now this method gets called :)
    print("called numberOfSections")
    return 1
  }
  ...
```

An alternative approach would be to develop your base class based on `UITableViewController` which already brings most of the things you need (a table view, delegate conformance, and default implementations of the delegate methods).

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, the main point of my solution is of course what the OP explicitly *didn't* want to do, sorry for that... in my defense, it was a lengthy post ;) Still, until someone with a deeper understanding of Swift's type system comes around and sheds some light on the issue, I'm afraid that it still is the best thing you can do if you don't wand to fall back to `UITableViewController`.

Comment: This is exactly what @Bill _didn't_ want to do

Comment: Right - I _could_ do this, but then I need to ensure that every method is overridden and update them as `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` change over time.